# Converting Latitude, Longitude in Decimals to the pixels for plotting markers on a plane svg image

Tags: javascript, dictionary, maps, interactive

I can see many answers to this question, but I don't clearly seem to follow most of those.

What I have been trying is to create an interactive world map with dynamic markers based on given latitudes and longitudes.

I have tried various equations found online but couldn't get the closer result.

The things I have tried so far,

```js
var y = Math.round(((-1 * lat) + 90) * (containerHeight / 180));
var x = Math.round((lon + 180) * (containerWidth / 360));
```

```js
x = R * Math.cos(lat) * Math.cos(lon)
y = R * Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(lon)
```

```js
var x = 1.9928145063077821*1000000 - 14017.262662576404*lat + 19202.720184031*lon;
var y = 334427.99241686985 - 33618.80202858345*lat - 14069.747257820272*lon;
```

Is there any better of implementing the same? Mercator, Azimuthal, Cylindrical ?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "Web Mercator". Google, Bing, OpenStreetMap uses this one and its kind a standard for web now. I don't have experience and enough information about calculation methods but formula which given on Wikipedia may help you.

[image: Web Marcator Formula]